# CSS Select and style bold text within a pre element

Tags: css

I am reading the Java Tutorials Online, and sometimes you can find snippets of code declared with the pre tag. These snippets include plain text and some of it is in bold. I can't really differentiate normal text from bold text, so I'm using my browser's Stylish extension to create a CSS style that will modify the page's look and feel replacing the original.
My goal is to change the color of the bold text inside the pre element to a color slightly different than black, like a very dark blue.
What CSS selector can I use to select only bold text in a pre tag. Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify what the markup is. (And then the question becomes rather simple.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select bold text within the pre element you need to write the following CSS rule:

```
pre b{
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: This selects `b` elements inside a `pre` element. There is no guarantee that bold text has been implemented that way; it can also be a e.g. `span` elements with a suitable class and a CSS rule using a class selector.